# Debo retornar true si la propiedad online del array de objetos usuarios es false y viceversa

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, formato-condicional, this

```
La funcion llamada "estaOffline" recibe como argumento un array de objetos llamado 'usuarios' y un string llamada 'nombre'.
Cada objeto tiene una property 'nombre' que es un string y otra llamada 'online' que es un booleano.
La función debe retornar true si el usuario se encuentra offline, de lo contrario false.
  /*ej:
   var usuarios = [
      {nombre: 'toni',
       online: true},
      {nombre: 'emi', online: true},
      {nombre: 'agus', online: false}];*/
```

// estaOffline(usuarios, 'agus') retorna true
// estaOffline(usuarios, 'emi') retorna false

```
function estaOffline(usuarios, nombre) {
```

Aplico un condicional if para saber si el usuario se encuentra o no conectado

```
  if(this.online){return false;} return true;}
```

Comment: Prueba invirtiendo el valor original: `return !this.online;`

Comment: this dentro de estaOffline te de undefined lo cual es un falsy value esto hace que siempre te retorne true 
this dentrro de estaOffline  no existe

Comment: entonces como lo soluciono?

Comment: Dentro de tu función estaOffline
```return !usuarios.find(usuario => usuario.nombre === nombre).online```

Comment: aplicando un condicional o un bucle for? y si la función recibe otros valores externos. El .find todavía no lo entiendo bien.

Comment: Find recorre todo el array y busca que el valor de parametro nombre coincida con el valor del tu key nombre si es true re regresa ese valor 
ejemplo {nombre: 'agus', online: false}

entonces hace el return asi:
` return !usuarios.find(usuario => usuario.nombre === nombre).online`
ten en cuenta el signo de admiracion ! 


`estaOffline(usuarios,'agus')`

`function estaOffline(usuarios, nombre) {
   return !usuarios.find(usuario => usuario.nombre === nombre).online
}`

Comment: ok muchas gracias!